# Почему не кэшируются картинки?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, битрикс, 1с

Использую CMS Bitrix. В корне сайта файл .htaccess с таким содержимым:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|text|bmp|psd)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172000"
    Header append Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi|html)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 172000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 172000 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

Как видите, для кэширования использую headers и expires. Так вот, захожу на https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ и проверяю - говорит "Используйте кэш браузера" и ссылается на то, что для файлов .jpg и .png не установлен срок кэширования! Но из кода выше видно, что установлен! В чем может быть дело?

Вот на всякий случай: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmuse.ooo%2F

Comment: Проверьте подключены ли модули `mod_headers` и `mod_expires.c`. `/usr/sbin/apache2 -l` или `/usr/sbin/httpd -l` или в файле `httpd.conf`. Может быть они закомментированы или не установлены.